# How to pass control to a new window(not popup) in selenium?

Tags: selenium

My site has a link which navigate to another site. I have to check whether the link taking the user to correct website. The following is the code i've written to pass control

```
        selenium.click("link=target window");
        selenium.selectWindow("Title of target window");
        assertTrue((selenium.isTextPresent("content in target window")));
        selenium.close();
        selenium.selectWindow("null");
```

But if i run this i'm getting error like "Could not find window with title ... "

Comment: What browser?  What version of Selenium?  There is possibly an [open issue with FF8 and 2.13](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1665).

Comment: firefox 3.6.. selenium version 2.18..

Answer (score 0):

There is information about how the `selectWindow()` function locates the window [here](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/dotnet/Selenium.DefaultSelenium.SelectWindow.html).  In particular,

> If you're having trouble figuring out what is the name of a window
>   that you want to manipulate, look at the selenium log messages which
>   identify the names of windows created via window.open (and therefore
>   intercepted by selenium). You will see messages like the following for
>   each window as it is opened:

```
    debug: window.open call intercepted;
    window ID (which you can use with selectWindow()) is "myNewWindow"
```